# Checking for Registry Value Of Computers in an Organizational Unit

Tags: powershell, outlook

Looking to gather information from Computers in an OU regarding mailboxes that were manually added and not added manually.

I'm pretty sure that the hive I need to target is:
HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook

I'm looking for a value of:
@example.example.edu

If that value is present I'd like it to output that value to a log file along with the user name it's attached to. If it's not present I'd like that outputted to a log file also.

Is test-registry value the right way to go?

How would you get the values for the computers in an OU?

Sorry for all the questions - still learning.

Comment: first, where is your code? second what are you mean 'were manually added and not added manually. ' do you want to know which outlook profiles configured on each computer?

Comment: Still working on it. My problem is that I believe I have the logic down it's just the syntax I seem to always struggle with.

Comment: And here's an example of what the manually added mailbox looks like in outlook  http://i.imgur.com/N6gVcdT.jpg

Comment: can't you just find who has mailbox permissions on those mailboxes? if user has no permission, he can't add it as an additional mailbox...